# Cohomology of $SU(n)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, spectral-sequences

Context:

I am trying to show that $H^{\ast}(SU(n))\cong\Lambda[x_{3},\dots x_{2n-1}]$.

My approach was to use induction- $SU(2)\cong S^3$ so $H^{\ast}(SU(2))\cong H^{\ast}(S^3)\cong\Lambda[x_{3}]$ so the base case is easy. Then, I tried to apply the Serre spectral sequence on
$$SU(n)\to SU(n+1)\to S^{2n+1}$$

assuming that $H^{\ast}(SU(n))\cong\Lambda[x_{3},\dots x_{2n-1}]$. The $E_{2}$ page will look like:

$$E_{2}^{p,q}=H^{p}(S^{2n+1};H^{q}(SU(n))=\begin{cases}H^{q}(SU(n)) & \text{ if } p=0,2n+1 \\
0 & \text{ otherwise } \end{cases}$$

However, I realised that I wasn't sure if I could deduce what $H^{p}(SU(n))$ was from $H^{\ast}(SU(n))$.

So my question is: can I deduce $H^{p}(SU(n))$ from $H^{\ast}(SU(n))$? If so, how and what will it be?

Comment: You have the $E_2$ page wrong. For a fibration $F\to E\to B$, you should have $E_2^{p, q} = H^p(B; H^q(F))$, but you are offering us $H^p(F; H^q(B))$ ($B=S^{2n+1}, F=SU(n)$).

Comment: @NelliKuukeri thanks- it should be right now.

Comment: Do you know how to use multiplicativity of the Serre spectral sequence?

Comment: @VincentBoelens Do you mean something like showing that it will collapse on the $E_2$ page?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I didn't check carefully, but multiplicatively the $E_2$-page should look like $\Lambda[y]\otimes \Lambda[x_3,\ldots, x_{2n-1}]$, all the generators should be killed for degree reasons, so the spectral sequence collapses.